# Promise<ConsumerStream> is not assignable to type Promise<void>

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to figure out why is I get this error during the build process (`npm run build`):

```
ERROR: src/setup/kafka/index.ts:147:29 - error TS2322: Type ''.
  Type 'ConsumerStream' is not assignable to type 'void'.
147             shutdown: () => Promise.resolve(stream.destroy()),
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/app.types.ts:26:15
    26     shutdown: () => Promise<void>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.
```

Where `stream` is a `kafka.ConsumerStream` instance (see `node-rdkafka`)

`stream.destroy()` returns `void`, i.e `destroy(error?: Error): void;`

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of `ConsumerStream.destroy` is `ConsumerStream` (see type details with links at the bottom of this answer). You can refactor your method by prefixing the invocation of `stream.destroy` with the [`void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void#non-leaking_arrow_functions):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbxgTzAUzgYQgOwM4CuIaUAyjFGgIYgC+cAZlBCHAOQ4QAmaAtFFwDWVBsLYBuALAAoGTwDGAGyqU483HnibKNAFxYNREuR0gp07dRAA6HtojIAFAEpxcAPTuD+I2QpWZGRR0OABJHCUCO1IACwIYLggAdxw4AF5EGTg4PDiE5Jx9F3SAPjgABWYQYDw0AB4ANwhgLhLzWnMZdXx4MGYAI0U0ECoYYHl9cMjovMSU9MzpbNz4ucK4KjxkCLhitLLLGls0eydnABoPACos7Lv7h8e7gD1Xt-eP55kAFVQMNkqLBq9WwPmIflMJTYcBqcE48E2eGAAHMcFRBhgYBA4MF-oDqrVGs1WmxrLdfiE2KDCOCTFZobD4Rs8EjUeihjjsbj2E0WqTHAAmADMAoFzjgV3cMg6gWk3U0cAggkmEUUUROsVWBQWCFuK3yKX0m228l24v2cF5XBy-iOdgoDhc52l5iAA)

```ts
import {type ConsumerStream} from 'node-rdkafka';

declare const stream: ConsumerStream;
stream.destroy(); // ConsumerStream

type IncludesShutdown = {
  shutdown: () => Promise<void>;
};

const problematic: IncludesShutdown = {
  shutdown: async () => stream.destroy(), /*
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Type 'Promise<ConsumerStream>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'.
  Type 'ConsumerStream' is not assignable to type 'void'.(2322) */
};

const ok: IncludesShutdown = {
  shutdown: async () => void stream.destroy(),
};
```

---

Type details for `ConsumerStream['destroy']`:

https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/blob/v2.12.0/index.d.ts#L137

```
export interface ConsumerStream extends Readable {
```

https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/blob/v2.12.0/index.d.ts#L1

```
import { Readable, ReadableOptions, Writable, WritableOptions } from 'stream';
```

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/20217c8228ad3837045c450e389fe92e8598cdd7/types/node/stream.d.ts#L411

```
// declare module 'stream' {
  // class Readable extends Stream implements NodeJS.ReadableStream {
    destroy(error?: Error): this;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I've tried it but I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I'm currently looking for information to understand why it is happening.

Comment: @Tomer Understood. However, that error is not related to the information in your question. You are, of course, welcome to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about the specifics of that error. Does the information I've provided answer your question, which is about type usage?

Comment: your answer helped me discover the underline issue behind this type usage. So I'll take it as an answer. Thanks :)